# Use HtmlUnit to Launch Application on Client Machine

Tags: java, httpclient, protocols, htmlunit, httpexception

I'm trying to launch an application by clicking a button on a webpage using HtmlUnit.
The url contains a protocol which HttpClient doesn't support. The protocol makes it so when you click the link, it will launch an application on your machine by also passing it certain parameters.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    System.out.println("Downloading DarkScape webpage...");
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://darkscape.runescape.com/game");
    System.out.println("Finding play button...");
    DomElement playButton = page.getElementById("yes-play-now");
    System.out.println("Clicking play button...");
    try{
        page = playButton.click();
        System.out.println("Launching DarkScape!");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Failed :(");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

The error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2067)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.doClickStateUpdate(HtmlAnchor.java:125)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.doClickStateUpdate(HtmlAnchor.java:162)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:786)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:733)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:680)
at me.jaylynn.darkscapelauncher.DarkScapeLauncher.main(DarkScapeLauncher.java:22)

Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:179)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1321)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1238)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2063)
... 6 more

Caused by: org.apache.http.HttpException: jagex-jav protocol is not supported
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultRoutePlanner.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:124)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:183)
... 11 more
```

Is there any way to add support for the "jagex-jav" protocol from HtmlUnit?
If not, then is there any way to get the parameters that would be passed to the application without having to click on the link?

Answer (score 0):

`jagex-jav` is not supported by real browsers, so it is out of scope for HtmlUnit.

You can get the request sent by HtmlUnit by intercepting the request, as hinted [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse).

Below is an example that prints all request URLs with their headers.

```
        new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {

            public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
                System.out.println(request.getUrl());
                System.out.println(request.getAdditionalHeaders());
                WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
                return response;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This doesn't seem to get the parameters that's passed to the application when the jagex-jav link is clicked. How do real browsers handle jagex-jav and other protocols like it which open? I've been having trouble finding anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer my question of how to make HtmlUnit support jagex-jav, but it does provide a workaround. Instead of clicking on the button, I just got the href and used Desktop to open the uri.

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
        try{
            String href = playButton.getAttribute("href");
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(href));
            System.out.println("Launching DarkScape!");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Failed :(");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```